# Прочитать большой xml (несколько Гб)

Tags: xml, python-3.x

Имеется несколько .xml файлов, размером от 1,5 до 7 Гб.
Каждый необходимо прочитать и забрать данные.
Мой скрипт валится в ошибку MemoryError
Может кто подскажет как обрабатывать такие большие файлы, не обладая таким же большим объемом памяти?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xml_file = 'M:\\SL\\sF140417\\SFR_mod.xml'
name = 'SFR_20170414_3'
tree = etree.ElementTree(file=xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()

"""Заполнение"""
records = root.findall('.//record')
ls = []
for i in range(len(records)):
    m = []
    for record in records[i]:
        m.append(record.get('value').replace(';', ''))
    ls.append(m)

src2 = open('insert_' + name + '.txt', 'w')
for i in ls:
    src2.write(';'.join(i) + '\n')
src2.close()
```

Comment: Большие файлы обрабатывают потоковыми парсерами типа sax или expat

Comment: нужно использовать генераторы(собственный велосипед) или как в ответе выше